# why hvplot does not run successfully

Tags: bokeh, hvplot

```
loan_amnt_box = data.hvplot.box(
    y='loan_amnt', subplots=True, by='loan_status', width=300, height=350, 
    title="Loan Status by Loan Amount ", xlabel='Loan Status', ylabel='Loan Amount'
)

installment_box = data.hvplot.box(
    y='installment', subplots=True, by='loan_status', width=300, height=350, 
    title="Loan Status by Installment", xlabel='Loan Status', ylabel='Installment'
)

loan_amnt_box + installment_box
```

I run the above code and got the following error messages. Couldn't figure out what went wrong. Actually, I had no clue at all. Can anyone please take a look at this.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Bug in Holoview, which should be solved by this [change](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/pull/5180) in the lastes version. The line of the error now looks like this:

> [#L276](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/90045175a4bf51d678cbdf1fa52f4b97769c7699/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/path.py#L276) `legend_prop = 'legend_field' if bokeh_version >= LooseVersion('1.3.5') else 'legend'`

Try to update holoviews using `pip install holoviews -U`. This should solve the problem. Afterwards run your example again.

The latest version of holoviews is 1.15.0.

Comment: Sweet! The problem is solved.